# Why does my JavaScript function see a mouseevent instead of an empty variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm attaching an eventlistener to a button on a page. When clicked, it runs a function.

`harvestDataBtn.addEventListener("click", harvestData, false);`

The function optionally takes a value.

`function harvestData(idsToHarvest)`

I don't want the clicking of the button to pass anything into the function. The optional variable `idsToHarvest` is used in other instances of the function being called, separate from the click.

However, when I click the button, `idsToHarvest` is a mouseevent. Making this code below inside my function not work as intended.

```
if ( idsToHarvest ) {
  // do something with string
} else {
  // button was clicked, do something else
}
```

Comment: The browser passes the event object to your event handler function. That's the way event handlers work. How is the browser to know that it should pass something else?

Comment: I understand that now. Is there any way to allow my function to pull double duty?

Comment: You could make *another* function that calls your current handler and passes it what it expects. You'd use that wrapper function as the handler.

Comment: Yes, but I'd highly discourage it. sooner as you think, you'll add a third use case and your function does triple duty, and so on. This only increases complexity in your function and the probability of errors. As Pointy said, use another function that calls `harvestData` with the arguments it needs for that specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the event listener a function that wraps your desired call to `harvestData` and ignore the event object that is passed by default:

`harvestDataBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e){harvestData();}, false);`

Answer (score 0):

```
el.addEventListener("click", function (event){ ... });
```

The 2nd param, in this case, a function, expects the argument passed in to be the event object.

If you are using that same function for other purposes and expect the argument to be something else, it won't work as an event handler.

From [the spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#callbackdef-eventlistener), it states:

> An event listener consists of these fields:
>
> - *type* (a string)
> - ***callback* (an `EventListener`)**
> - *capture* (a boolean, initially false)
> - *passive* (a boolean, initially false)
> - *once* (a boolean, initially false)
> - *removed* (a boolean for bookkeeping purposes, initially false)

As stated, it shows the `callback` is actually an `EventListener`, which is defined by the interface shown:

```
callback interface EventListener {
    void handleEvent(Event event);
};
```

As you can see, when the callback is evaluated and the `handleEvent` is called, it accepts 1 argument, **event** of the type `Event`.